# Mailchimp - Delete a list via api

Tags: mailchimp

Is there a way to delete a list using MailChimp api? currently I am using `listUnsubscribe` but I want to completely remove the list.

Answer (score 1):

The [list-related API docs](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/#listrelated) don't have any hooks to delete a list, just members from a list.

Answer (score 1):

MailChimp API v3 supports deleting a list.
You can delete the MailChimp list by sending a **DELETE** request to the `lists/{list_id}/` endpoint.

**An example request,**

```
curl --request DELETE \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/4ca5becb8d' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--include
```

Please note that by deleting a list, you’ll lose the list history—including subscriber activity, unsubscribes, complaints, and bounces. You’ll also lose subscribers’ email addresses unless you exported and backed up your list.

Answer (score 0):

listBatchUnsubscribe has the option to delete_member:
https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listbatchunsubscribe.func.php